# Multiplication with date object - javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I came across this piece of code `var timeStamp = 1 * new Date();` and to my surprise it returned value in milliseconds since 1970/01/01. This is equivalent to using `.getTime()` method!

What's happening under the hood? Does Type Conversion concept work here, which basically converts `new Date()` value into the milliseconds?

Comment: Multiplication (or any arithmetic operation) causes a Date object to be converted to a number for the sake of evaluating the expression. It could also use `+new Date()` or `new Date() / 1`, etc.

Comment: When you use multiplication, internally it call the Date's prototype valueOf function which returns the value in millisecond

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's happening under the hood?

The short version:

Because it's being used in a math operation, the date is converted to a number, and when you convert dates to numbers, the number you get is the milliseconds-since-the-Epoch (e.g., `getTime()`).

The long version:

1. The [multiplication operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5) calls the abstract operation [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) on its operands.
2. For objects like `Date`s, that calls the abstract operation [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) on the object, with the "preferred type" being "number".
3. For most types of objects (including `Date`s), `ToPrimitive` calls the abstract operation [`[[DefaultValue]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8), passing along the preferred type as the "hint".
4. `[[DefaultValue]]` with hint = "number" calls `valueOf` on the object. (`valueOf` is a real method, unlike the abstract operations above.)
5. For `Date` objects, [`valueOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.8) returns the "time value," the value you get from `getTime`.

---

Side note: There's no reason I can think of to use `var timeStamp = 1 * new Date()` rather than, say, `var timeStamp = +new Date()`, which has the same effect. Or of course, on any modern engine (and the shim is trivial), `var timeStamp = Date.now()` ([more on `Date.now`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.4)).

Comment: I wrote it that way just to make the question simpler. Actually the code snippet was of Google Analytics you can check here the same > [link](http://pastie.org/9283205)

Comment: @Manaday: It doesn't affect the answer explaining what's going on. :-) Just FWIW, there's still no reason for throwing a `*` in there, you could replace `i[r].l = 1 * new Date()` with `i[r].l = +new Date()` or `i[r].l = Date.now()` without changing the result. (Although GA wouldn't want to use `Date.now` because some older browsers don't have it.) But the `1 * new Date()` version is harmless, of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Numeric conversion**

It is because of numeric conversion in javascript which is almost same like toString but internally it is called much more often.

Numeric conversion is performed in two main cases:

- In functions which needs a number: for example Math.sin(obj), isNaN(obj), including arithmetic operators: +obj.
- In comparisons, like obj == 'John'.
  The exceptions are the string equality ===, because it doesn’t do any type conversion, and also non-strict equality when both arguments are objects, not primitives: obj1 == obj2. It is true only if both arguments reference the same object.

The explicit conversion can also be done with Number(obj).

The algorithm of numeric conversion:

- If valueOf method exists and returns a primitive, then return it.
- Otherwise, if toString method exists and returns a primitive, then return it.
- Otherwise, throw an exception.

Among built-in objects, Date supports both numeric and string conversion:

```
alert( new Date() ) // The date in human-readable form
alert( 1*new Date() ) // Microseconds from 1 Jan 1970
```

[**Further reading**](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/the-value-of-valueof/)