# Why do arithmetic operations work on dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have read the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript) on SO, but here I am asking why the below semantics are allowed

Take the following Javascript example:

```
window - window = NaN

window - document = NaN
```

but

```
new Date() - new Date() = 0
new Date / new Date() = 1
new Date * new Date() = 2.2659874948410516e+24
```

Why does this work ? These code snippets were executed in Chrome console and I have a couple of questions about what is happening here:

**Firstly**, why is it even allowed in Javascript to do arithmetic operations on Date ? Is it a special type of object that is magically allowed these abilities ? Is Date even treated internally as an object ? Why then even force us to create a Date() like a normal object ?

**Secondly**, what does it even mean to subtract, or multiply two dates ?

**Thirdly**, is Date the only exception or are there other object that have these "superpowers"(*other than string*), also can they be replicated in user-defined code ?

Comment: Because js isn't a strong typed language., check this out; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182317/multiplication-with-date-object-javascript

Comment: Because JS date is essentially the count of miliseconds from 1st January 1970?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement it yourself ( *be superman!*). Using the `+*-/` on an object tries to convert that object to a primitive through either calling one of these:

```
obj.toString() //if string is required
obj.valueOf() // if number is required
```

So to make that behaviour, just define that methods:

```
class one {
 valueOf(){ return 1; }
}

alert( new one + new one)//2
```

Comment: So how does Javascript know when String is toString() and when valueOf() is required ? Like for Strings '+' means concatenation, but the example given above means valueOf(), If both are implemented how does JS know what to call ?

Comment: @mg.newbie -/* => valueOf, + => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

JS supports a rudimentary form of operator overloading so that arithmetic operators, when applied to an object, invoke its special `valueOf` method to obtain a numeric value:

```js
a = {};
a.valueOf = () => 1;

b = {};
b.valueOf = () => 2;

console.log(a + b)
```

`Date` objects define `valueOf` so that it returns milliseconds from the epoch.

Note that `valueOf` is only invoked in the "numeric" context, which is the case for `- * /`, but not for `+`. If you're going to add something to a Date, convert to the `Number` first:

```js
today = new Date
tomorrow = new Date(Number(today) + 24 * 3600 * 1000)
console.log(tomorrow)
```